# SQLite Dilemma: Editing InitialValues

Tags: android, sqlite, android-intent

I'm creating an android app that has "User Login" page. I've try using SQlite and this is my code:

```
package tsu.ccs.capstone;

import android.content.ContentValues;  
import android.content.Context;  
import android.database.Cursor;  
android.database.SQLException;  
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase;  
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteOpenHelper;  
import android.util.Log;  

public class DBUser {
    public static final String KEY_ROWID = "_id";  
    public static final String KEY_USERNAME= "username";  
    public static final String KEY_PASSWORD = "password";  
    private static final String TAG = "DBAdapter";  

private static final String DATABASE_NAME = "usersdb";  
private static final String DATABASE_TABLE = "users";  
private static final int DATABASE_VERSION = 1;  

private static final String DATABASE_CREATE =  
    "create table users (_id integer primary key autoincrement, "  
    + "username text not null, "  
    + "password text not null);";  

private Context context = null;  
private DatabaseHelper DBHelper;  
private SQLiteDatabase db;  

public DBUser(Context ctx)  
{  
    this.context = ctx;  
    DBHelper = new DatabaseHelper(context);  
}  

private static class DatabaseHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper  
{  
    DatabaseHelper(Context context)  
    {  
        super(context, DATABASE_NAME, null, DATABASE_VERSION);  
    }  

    @Override  
    public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db)  
    {  
        db.execSQL(DATABASE_CREATE);  
    }  

    @Override  
    public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion)  
    {  
        Log.w(TAG, "Upgrading database from version " + oldVersion  
                + " to "  
                + newVersion + ", which will destroy all old data");  
        db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS users");  
        onCreate(db);  
    }  
}      

public void open() throws SQLException  
{  
    db = DBHelper.getWritableDatabase();  
}  

public void close()  
{  
    DBHelper.close();  
}      

public long AddUser(String username, String password)  
{  
     ContentValues initialValues = new ContentValues();  
     initialValues.put(KEY_USERNAME, "p");  
     initialValues.put(KEY_PASSWORD, "p");  
     return db.insert(DATABASE_TABLE, null, initialValues);  

}  

public boolean Login(String username, String password) throws SQLException  
{  
    Cursor mCursor = db.rawQuery("SELECT * FROM " + DATABASE_TABLE + " WHERE username=? AND password=?", new String[]{username,password});  
    if (mCursor != null) {  
        if(mCursor.getCount() > 0)  
        {  
            return true;  
        }  
    }  
 return false;  
}  

}
```

as you can see, I have a InitialValue for my username and password field in my layout.
my problem is I want to give the user an option to change the default username and password that I set. Simply put, just overwrite the InitialValues then save my database.

Can anyone help me, I'm only beginning android programming and I'm at lost with this one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Java does not support default parameters value so you will have to overload AddUser function.

```
    public long AddUser(){  
     ContentValues initialValues = new ContentValues();  
     initialValues.put(KEY_USERNAME, "p");  
     initialValues.put(KEY_PASSWORD, "p");  
     return db.insert(DATABASE_TABLE, null, initialValues);
   }
```

This will create user with your default username and password.

```
   public long AddUser(String username, String password){  
     ContentValues initialValues = new ContentValues();  
     initialValues.put(KEY_USERNAME, username);  
     initialValues.put(KEY_PASSWORD, password);  
     return db.insert(DATABASE_TABLE, null, initialValues);
  }
```

This function will create user with the value provided by user.

Comment: hmmm.. it works. but it only adds another set of username and password. my goal is to overwrite the previously entered Username and Password. so that it can't be used again.